# Setting constant width on subview of UIStackView when axis is vertical

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I have a UIScrollView that contains a UIStackView, and I add views to it and if the UIStackView needs more space than the screen has then it will scroll thanks to the UIScrollView.

I am able to set constant heights on the views, but I also need to set a specific width on them, so that they have a specific width and are also centered in the stack view.

Something like this, except the widthAnchor does not work.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let sv = UIScrollView()
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sv.backgroundColor = .gray
        return sv
    }()

    let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let sv = UIStackView()
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sv.axis = .vertical
        return sv
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

        stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true

        let view1 = UIView()
        view1.backgroundColor = .red

        let view2 = UIView()
        view2.backgroundColor = .blue

        let view3 = UIView()
        view3.backgroundColor = .green

        let view4 = UIView()
        view4.backgroundColor = .purple

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(view1)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(view2)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(view3)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(view4)

        view1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        view2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
        view3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 420).isActive = true
        view4.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

        // This does not work.
//        view1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `alignment` property on a UIStackView determines how its layout works **perpendicular** to its axis. By default, a UIStackView has an alignment of `fill`. In constraint terms, `fill` is like adding a constraint to (in this case) the left and right edges of the stack view for each arranged subview. These implicit constraints are likely causing your problem. **Solution: set `stackView.alignment =` either `leading`, `center`, or `trailing` depending on your desired effect**.

Comment: And if you want the stackview to be wider, use the stackview's width anchor.